# How to change/select your nickname for IRC using NickServ

Tags: irc

Real beginner with IRC so bear with me.

NickServ appears to be some sort of external 'application' that allows you to register and sign into IRCs.

**To register:**

```
/msg nickserv register <password> <email>
```

**To 'sign in' (identify):**

```
/msg nickserv identify <name_password> <email>
```

Upon registering, I get this email:

```
jimboF2,

In order to complete your registration, you must send the following
command on IRC:
/msg NickServ VERIFY REGISTER jimboF2 xasdao231d
```

So where did `jimboF2` come from and how can I change it?

Also, upon [using a different irc client](http://www.irssi.org/), it thinks my nick name is `james_`, the username of my Ubuntu account. I can't seem to change it to `jimboF2`.

```
07:49 < james_> sdfsd
07:49 -!- #ruby-lang Cannot send to channel
```

Attempting to sign in just does nothing at all. Literally nothing

```
/msg nickserv identify jimboF2 myemail@email.com
```

Comment: Maybe JimboF2 is your 'current' nickname when you register for the first time? (When you send the first /msg nickserv register password email )

Comment: I think so. Is it generated by Nickserv?

Comment: @Starkers - You don't know what your current nick is?  You selected it.

Comment: @Ramhound It could be that the client OP uses gets a nick using the comouter username, XChat does this by default. And the webchat mibbit gives random nicknames... It could be that there's something like that happening on whatever client OP's using to access IRC.

Comment: @Jerry - Its entirely possible thats the case, but when they send a message, they still would know their current nick.

Comment: One can get the help from nickserv using "/msg NickServ help". It prints all the available commands.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In IRC, (not sure what client you're using) you usually can change your nickname by using:

```
/nick NewName
```

And if you want to 'lock' that name for your own use (assuming no one else has registered that nickname, you do that command as what you have done:

```
/msg NickServ register password email
```

Which then NickServ will attempt to warn other people (when you're offline) if they are trying to use your name, saying that your name is registered, and they need to either:

1. Identify as you by doing `/msg nickserv identify password` (not sure if email is required, but it depends on the IRC server)
2. Get 'kicked' out by NickServ, or Forced-Name-Change by NickServ if you / the person using your nickname unable to identify themselves within certain period of time - again depends on the IRC server setting.

So looks like you have accidentally registered JimboF2. If you don't want it, ignore it, simply change your name to a name that you want to register, and try to register the name again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Identify failed as XXXX. You know why because i tried to change to my nickname and cannot do. So i can't ident, because when i try to change nick it doesn't allow me to, and i can't identify with a different nick. Thanks for YOUR TOTALLY USELESS ANSWER.