# Irssi is simply ignoring any attempt to register of identify

Tags: irssi

```
irssi
```

Launches irrsi

```
/connect irc.freenode.net
```

connects to freenode.

```
/join #ruby-lang
```

joins the ruby-lang room.

I can see people talking, but I can't talk. There is a blue bar at the top saying

`'Nick registration required to talk'.`

at the bottom:

```
[08:15] [james_(+i)] [2:freenode/#ruby-lang(+cnt)] [Act: 1,3]                 
[#ruby-lang]
```

Whatever I type to the right of [#ruby-lang] is simply ignored.

```
/msg NickServ REGISTER <my_password> <my_email>
```

nothing.

```
/msg NickServ IDENTIFY <my_nick> <my_password>
```

nothing.

```
/nick AnotherNick
```

nothing. Seriously, the command just disappears and nothing happens.

What's going on?

This brings up nickserv's help dialogue:

```
/query nickserv help register
```

though I don't know how to then exit 'NickServ'. When inside 'NickServ' I can type

```
/msg
```

for some help. So I type it, hit enter and....nothing. Really annoying.

Comment: What's the output of the status window after those commands? Does the Irssi documentation say anything about this behavior?

Comment: Isn't this the same question as http://superuser.com/questions/657548/how-to-change-select-your-nickname-for-irc-using-nickserv

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are not ignored.

As your Irssi status shows,

> **`[Act: 1,3]`**

…there is activity in Irssi windows #1 and #3. My guess is that #3 is a private-message window from NickServ (while #1 is almost always the "server messages" window).

In the former you'll see replies to the REGISTER and IDENTIFY commands, while the latter has an error message along the lines of "Cannot change nick while banned on channel". (The restriction from speaking for unregistered users is implemented in the form of a special ban.)

In Irssi, the usual ways of switching windows are:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + {<kbd>1</kbd>…<kbd>9</kbd>} as well as <kbd>Alt</kbd> + {<kbd>q</kbd>, <kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd>, …} to jump between the first 20 windows;
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> for next/previous window;
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to jump to the first *active* window;
- `/window`  (short: `/win` ) to jump to a window numbered ;
- `/query nick` and `/unquery` to open or close a private-message window;
- &c.

Comment: helped me out so much!